# Need to find efficient method to find Strong number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Written a program to find the find the Strong number

A number is considered to be a Strong number if sum of the factorial of its digits is equal to the number itself. 
145 is a Strong number as 1! + 4! + 5! = 145.

Need to accept a list, find the Strong Number among the list and return a list of same

Ive tried :

```
def factorial(number):
    if number == 0 or number == 1:
        return 1
    else :
        return number * factorial(number - 1)


def find_strong_numbers(num_list):
    sum = 0
    ret_list = []
    for i in num_list :
        sum = 0
        lst = list(map(int,list(str(i))))   #Converting the number into a list of numbers
        for j in lst :
            sum += factorial(j)
        if sum == i :
            ret_list.append(i)
    return ret_list

num_list=[145,375,100,2,10]
strong_num_list=find_strong_numbers(num_list)
print(strong_num_list)
```

In the above example, I have created a list of the digits of the number and found its factorial.
But,

```
def factorial(number):
    if number == 0 or number == 1:
        return 1
    else :
        return number * factorial(number - 1)


def find_strong_numbers(num_list):
    sum = 0
    ret_list = []
    for i in num_list :
        sum = 0
        lst = list(str(i))   #A List of Strings of the digits
        for j in lst :
            sum += factorial(int(j))
        if sum == i :
            ret_list.append(i)
    return ret_list

num_list=[145,375,100,2,10]
strong_num_list=find_strong_numbers(num_list)
print(strong_num_list)
```

Ive created a list of Strings of Digits in the number
Converted the string to number when calling the factorial function.
This seems to be efficient for me as I need not to convert it into a map and then to int(less conversion)

Is this correct, is this efficient than the previous one or is there any far better optimised Code than this to find Strong Number.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can simply memoize the `factorial` function to speed up the processing

   ```
   from functools import lru_cache

   @lru_cache(maxsize=128)
   def factorial(number):
       if number <= 1:
           return 1
       else:
           return number * factorial(number - 1)
   ```
2. Also, you can use a generator to get the next digit like this

   ```
   def get_next_digit(num):
       while num:
           yield num % 10
           num //= 10

   print(sum(factorial(digit) for digit in get_next_digit(145)))
   ```

   This avoids creating an intermittent list of strings.

---

PS: These are minor optimisations which may not greatly improve the performance of the program.

**Overall Code**

```
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(maxsize=128)
def factorial(number):
    if number <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return number * factorial(number - 1)


def get_next_digit(num):
    while num:
        yield num % 10
        num //= 10


def is_strong_number(num):
    return sum(factorial(digit) for digit in get_next_digit(num)) == num


def find_strong_numbers(num_list):
    return [num for num in num_list if is_strong_number(num)]


num_list = [145, 375, 100, 2, 10]
print(find_strong_numbers(num_list))
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by " memoize the factorial function ". And how does it speed up the rate

Comment: @SivaRahul If the result has been computed for a specific input, it will not be computed again.

Comment: @thefourtheye Seems `math.factorial()` with your `get_next_digit()` seems to be fastest solution, but `lru_cache` version isn't far behind.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're only using factorials of 0..9, there's no need to have a function to compute them, let alone a recursive one. You can just hardcode all 10 values:

```
facts = {'0': 1, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 6, '4': 24, '5': 120, '6': 720, '7': 5040, '8': 40320, '9': 362880}
```

and then simply use:

```
def is_strong(n):
    return sum(facts[s] for s in str(n)) == n
```

You can squeeze a bit more cycles of out this by avoiding a string conversion:

```
facts2 = [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880]

def is_strong2(n):
    s, k = 0, n
    while k:
        s += facts2[k % 10]
        k //= 10
    return s == n
```

...but given the fact that it's [proven](https://oeis.org/A014080) there are no such numbers beside `1, 2, 145, 40585`, the whole enterprise looks a bit pointless ;)

Comment: That's should be the accepted answer! Thinking out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Another version, using builtin `math.factorial` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.factorial)):

```
from math import factorial

def is_strong_number(num):
    return num == sum(factorial(int(c)) for c in str(num))

num_list=[145,375,100,2,10]
strong_num_list = [num for num in num_list if is_strong_number(num)]
print(strong_num_list)
```

Prints:

```
[145, 2]
```

Comment: Do the math.factorial differ from what i have used?

Comment: @SivaRahul No, they don't differ - it's the same factorial. Only difference is speed.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do.

The first thing that comes to mind is making the `factorial` function iterative, instead of recursive:

```py
def factorial(number):
    if number == 0 or number == 1:
        return 1

    result = 1

    for i in range(number + 1):
        result *= i

    return result
```

The second one would be to precompute all factorials for each digit, since there is a limited amount of them:

```py
def get_factorials():
    result = [1, 1]

    value = 1
    for i in range(2, 10):
        value *= i
        result.append(value)

    return result
```

Then, instead of calling `factorial` each time, you could just do:

```py
factorials = get_factorials()

lst = list(str(i))
for j in lst :
  sum += factorials[int(j)]
```

Your result function could then be as simple as:

```py
def is_strong_number(num):
    return num == sum(map(lambda x: factorials[int(x)], str(num))

def find_strong_numbers(nums):
    factorials = get_factorials()
    return [num for num in nums if is_strong_number(num)]
```

Edit: thanks [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood), fixed :)

Comment: What advantage does it give in using multiplication method over recursive one.. And precomputing would not be good as this is just a simple case, i may have a large set of values

Comment: @Siva Rahul Do you have numbers with digits other than 0, 1, 2... 9 in your large set of values? Why would precomputing not be good?

Comment: @Siva Rahul iteration is faster (single function call) and there is no chance of stack overflow (in case you decided you needed factorial of number 10000 for example).

Answer (score 1):

others have already suggested improvements in their answers,

just for the sake of demonstrating a more empirical approach to runtime benchmarking:

you can use `timeit` to compare the runtime of different functions.

I added both of yours, and also a version that doesn't do the string<->int casting at all.

```py
import timeit


def factorial(number):
    if number == 0 or number == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return number * factorial(number - 1)


def find_strong_numbers_with_map(num_list):
    sum = 0
    ret_list = []
    for i in num_list:
        sum = 0
        lst = list(map(int, list(str(i))))  # Converting the number into a list of numbers
        for j in lst:
            sum += factorial(j)
        if sum == i:
            ret_list.append(i)
    return ret_list


def find_strong_numbers_cast_on_call(num_list):
    sum = 0
    ret_list = []
    for i in num_list:
        sum = 0
        lst = list(str(i))  # A List of Strings of the digits
        for j in lst:
            sum += factorial(int(j))
        if sum == i:
            ret_list.append(i)
    return ret_list


def find_strong_numbers_by_div_mod(num_list):
    sum = 0
    ret_list = []
    for i in num_list:
        sum = 0
        while i > 0:
            j = i % 10  # get the value of the last digit
            sum += factorial(int(j))
            i = i // 10  # "cut" the last digit from i
        if sum == i:
            ret_list.append(i)
    return ret_list


num_list = [*range(1, 1000)]
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: find_strong_numbers_with_map(num_list), number=10 ** 3))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: find_strong_numbers_cast_on_call(num_list), number=10 ** 3))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: find_strong_numbers_by_div_mod(num_list), number=10 ** 3))
```

results on my laptop are:

```
2.4222552359969995
2.114583875001699
1.8628507399989758
```